# Use a Custom Controller on Product Page - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I have created a controller following the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html)

The module works just fine stand alone, however, I cannot add it to a page.  It will display in a product page if I call the template file but does not work.

```
<reference name="calculator">
<block type="core/template" name="calculatorBlock" template="calculator/calculator.phtml" />
</reference>
```

I suspect it is because it needs to be called differently to get the "whole" thing (models, etc.)

Can someone help point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding `<reference name="content">
            <block type="calculator/calculator" name="calculator" template="calculator/calculator.phtml"  />
</reference>` to the design portion of the product in the admin interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, you want to render your template in product page !

1) In your **layout.xml**:

```
<catalog_product_view>    
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="calculator.block" template="calculator/calculator.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

2) In `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` you add the code bellow where you want to display your block.

`<?php echo this->getBlockHtml('calculator.block') ?>`

Comment: This pushed me in the direction.  Thank you!  type "core/template" did not display the dynamic options from the model but using 'type=calculator/calculator' did the trick.